# .change function in a for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there anyway to put a `.change` function into a for loop instead of writing this function out 4 times because i need this same function but with `#room_Children1,2,3 and 4` and`.room#1,2,3 and 4`

```
$("#room_Children1").change(function () {
            switch ($("#room_Children1").val()) {
                case "1":
                    $(".room#1").children().next().next().first().show();
                    $(".room#1").children().next().next().next().first().hide();
                    $(".room#1").children().next().last().hide();
                    break;
                case "2":
                    $(".room#1").children().next().next().first().show();
                    $(".room#1").children().next().next().next().first().show();
                    $(".room#1").children().next().last().hide();
                    break;
                case "3":
                    $(".room#1").children().next().next().first().show();
                    $(".room#1").children().next().next().next().first().show();
                    $(".room#1").children().next().last().show();
                    break;
                case "0":
                    $(".room#1").children().next().next().hide();
                    break;
                default:
                    alert("You cheated");
                    break;
            }
});
```

Comment: do you intend to select elements with class `.room#1` *or* elements with class `.room` and id `1`? :O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the whole chunk in a function:

```
function foo(id) { // choose a better function name, can't think of one at the moment :s
        var classId = '.room#' + id;
        switch ($('#room_Children' + id).val()) {
            case "1":
                $(classId).children().next().next().first().show();
                $(classId).children().next().next().next().first().hide();
                $(classId).children().next().last().hide();
                break;
            case "2":
                $(classId).children().next().next().first().show();
                $(classId).children().next().next().next().first().show();
                $(classId).children().next().last().hide();
                break;
            case "3":
                $(classId).children().next().next().first().show();
                $(classId).children().next().next().next().first().show();
                $(classId).children().next().last().show();
                break;
            case "0":
                $(classId).children().next().next().hide();
                break;
            default:
                alert("You cheated");
                break;
        }
}
```

Then

```
$("#room_Children1, #room_Children2, #room_Children3, #room_Children4")
   .change(function() {
      var id = $(this).attr('id').replace('room_Children', '');
      foo(id);
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.each([1,2,3,4], function(i, num) {
    var $roomChildren = $("#room_Children" + num);
    $roomChildren.change(function () {
        var $room = $(".room#" + num);
        switch ($roomChildren.val()) {
            case "1":
                $room.children().next().next().first().show();
                $room.children().next().next().next().first().hide();
                $room.children().next().last().hide();
                break;
            case "2":
                $room.children().next().next().first().show();
                $room.children().next().next().next().first().show();
                $room.children().next().last().hide();
                break;
            case "3":
                $room.children().next().next().first().show();
                $room.children().next().next().next().first().show();
                $room.children().next().last().show();
                break;
            case "0":
                $room.children().next().next().hide();
                break;
            default:
                alert("You cheated");
                break;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: It doesn't recognise the .change if i have a for loop before the .change function

Comment: I changed the implementation for other reasons, but .change() should still work just fine with a for loop involved. Can you be more specific on what you mean by "it doesn't recognize the .change"? Are you seeing any errors?

Comment: The for loop is not even needed.

Comment: Well if we're being technical, you solution is really just substituting an explicit loop with an implicit one by jQuery. So there :p

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a for loop.  You have all the data needed within the Id of the element that has the change function bound.  Basically extract the number from the end of the ID and utilize this numeric value within the change function itself.

```
$("#room_Children1, #room_Children2, #room_Children3, #room_Children4").change(function () {
  var $this = $(this);
  var roomNumber = $this.attr("id")[$this.attr("id").length -1];
  switch ($this.val()) {
    case "1":
      $(".room#" + roomNumber).children().next().next().first().show();
      $(".room#" + roomNumber).children().next().next().next().first().hide();
      $(".room#" + roomNumber).children().next().last().hide();
      break;
    case "2":
      $(".room#" + roomNumber).children().next().next().first().show();
      $(".room#" + roomNumber).children().next().next().next().first().show();
      $(".room#" + roomNumber).children().next().last().hide();
      break;
    case "3":
      $(".room#" + roomNumber).children().next().next().first().show();
      $(".room#" + roomNumber).children().next().next().next().first().show();
      $(".room#1").children().next().last().show();
      break;
    case "0":
      $(".room#" + roomNumber).children().next().next().hide();
      break;
    default:
      alert("You cheated");
      break;
  }
});
```